# How do I traverse the filesystem looking for a regex match?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, unix-shell

I know this is teeball for veteran sysadmins, but I'm looking to search a directory tree for file contents that match a regex (here, the word "Keyword"). I've gotten that far, but now I'm having trouble ignoring files in a hidden (.svn) file tree.

Here's what I'm working with. You can see that I am fine searching for files that include ".svn" in the name but I can't seem to invert the iname var with a ! as I've see in other docs.

```
find . -exec grep "Keyword" '{}' \; -iname .svn; -print
```

The above returns pretty much anything and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . \( -iname '.svn' -prune \) -o \( -exec grep -q ... \; -print \)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about recursive grep:

```
grep -r --exclude "*.svn*" "Keyword" .
```